# FileBeat Setup Error : Payload content length greater than maximum allowed: 1048576

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, filebeat

We are working to capture logs from server to elasticsearch by filebeat.
We are getting below issue, while setup the filebeat.

Response: {"statusCode":413,"error":"Request Entity Too Large","message":"Payload content length greater than maximum allowed: 1048576"}

We have added http.max_content_length: 1200mb in elasticsearch.yml and server.maxPayloadBytes: 26214400 in kibana.yml. Still this issue is there.

How to resolve this issue?

Here is the YML files we are using for FileBeat, ElasticSearch & Kibana

**FileBeat.yml**

filebeat.inputs:

- type: log

  enabled: true
  paths:

  - c:\logs\XXX*
- type: filestream

  enabled: false

  paths:

  - /var/log/*.log

filebeat.config.modules:
path: ${path.config}/modules.d/*.yml

reload.enabled: false

setup.template.settings:
index.number_of_shards: 1

setup.kibana:

```
host: "0.0.0.0:0000"
username: "XXXX"
password: "XXXX"
```

output.elasticsearch:
hosts: ["0.0.0.0:0000"]

username: "XXXX"
password: "XXXX"

processors:

- add_host_metadata:
  when.not.contains.tags: forwarded
- add_cloud_metadata: ~
- add_docker_metadata: ~
- add_kubernetes_metadata: ~

**ElasticSearch.yml**

- module: elasticsearch
  server:
  enabled: true

  gc:
  enabled: true

  audit:
  enabled: true

  slowlog:
  enabled: true

  deprecation:
  enabled: true

  access:
  var.paths: ["/var/logs/XXX/XXX.log"]

  http.max_content_length: 1200mb

**Kibana.yml**

- module: kibana

  log:
  enabled: true

  audit:
  enabled: true

  server.maxPayloadBytes: 26214400

Comment: I found you have to restart kibana after you change that setting for it to take effect